# error: cannot find symbol this.mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, BuildConfig.FLAVOR, "Wait......");

Tags: android

error: cannot find symbol
this.mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, BuildConfig.FLAVOR, "Wait......");

The problem is as shown in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3T97.jpg)

Comment: It will be better is you add some information context about what are you trying to do. You have more information about BuildConfig.FLAVOR in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips